# Draw circle on an image Opencv4Android 3.1.0

Tags: opencv, android

There are solutions to this question using canvas, as stated in [Draw a circle on an existing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520287/draw-a-circle-on-an-existing-image). I am trying to use Opencv4Android 3.1.0 and have not been able to find the function to draw circle, like the ones present in the previous version, in the Core class.

Is it only me, or is this a problem with the new **Opencv4Android 3.1.0**? If not present in the **Core** class, then can anyone please point out where it is present now? Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

Am not able to find it even in my package. Does Opencv4Android 3.1.0 come without a function to draw a circle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Imgproc.circle(image, new Point(960,540), 500, new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 150), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the OpenCV code in C++
You can use the same OpenCV `circle` function stated in http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#circle

However, for the C++ file to import in Android, follow [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/df8/tutorial_dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV latest versions the Core class does not contain circle so now and onwards you must use the keyword "Imgproc.circle" to draw a circle.